# Divs move when zooming out. How do i use percentages when I have uneven number?

Tags: css, html, zooming, border

I'm trying to create a menu bar, but somehow, when zooming out my last button always goes out of the menu. But it doesn't stay there. Does anyone have an idea?

```
<div id="tip"></div>
<div id="top">
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menuButton"></div>
    <div class="menuButton"></div>
    <div class="menuButton"></div>
    <div class="menuButton"></div>
    <div class="menuButton"></div>
    <div class="menuButton"></div>
    <div class="menuButton2"></div>
</div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The HTML. The CSS is in the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/Legruan/f7nzu/

I made this fiddle with the code in it so far.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to use vieuwport ? this is how i fixed a problem like this

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
</head>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I think it might have to do with the border of the buttons, but I can only assume, since my knowledge only go so far.